# Inject asp.net core middleware from inside a library to a specific location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, xaf

I am developing a plugin and I need to inject another middleware into the user StartUp.cs, is there a way to it without modifying the user StartUp.cs?

The only way I can think of is actually patching the runtime and inject the required IL instructions to the start of `UseXaf` middleware that call my middleware first. However I am hoping there is build-in mechanism to it.

```cs
if(env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

//INJECT IT HERE <---------

app.UseXaf();
```

Comment: I think this question is still a bit unclear, about some constraints you pose on both the current user project & your plugin system. E.g: if we have full flexibility to modify the user code & design the plugin system accordingly, we can use normal DI to inject the services (loading module to build on the `IApplicationBuilder`), of course that extensibility point must be setup by placing a stub to where the user need in the `Configure` method (like where you pointed out in the question).

Comment: I will update my answer to make it crystal clear then.

Comment: I'm not so sure how your plugin system works, but there are surely 2 cases: a plugin will run before & after the code in the `Startup.cs`. Either ways may require a different approach to solve it. I'm pretty sure that there is no built-in mechanism to achieve what you want. Even a simple requirement to get all the registered middlewares need a hacky code (playing around with reflection, referencing the source code, ...). Anyway, the first problem you need to solve is how to target the point of injection before actually injecting the code. Hope you can solve this yourself, it's really tough :)

Comment: > a plugin will run before & after the code in the Startup.cs
I know about IStartupFilter

>the first problem you need to solve is how to target the point of injection 
The User Startup.cs is fixed, the UseXaf middleware always exist, the injection must be done exactly before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to actually patch the runtime and inject instructions to call my custom middleware just before the the `UseXaf` middleware.

It can be done easy with the https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony library as:

```cs
    public class UseHangfire : IStartupFilter {
        private static readonly Harmony Harmony=new Harmony(nameof(UseHangfire));
        static UseHangfire() {
            var methodInfo = typeof(StartupExtensions).Method(nameof(StartupExtensions.UseXaf),Flags.StaticPublic);
            Harmony.Patch(methodInfo,postfix:new HarmonyMethod(typeof(UseHangfire),nameof(UseXaf))); //runtime patching of the UseXaf middleware
        }

        public static void UseXaf(IApplicationBuilder builder) => Dashboard?.Invoke(builder); //inject the Hangfire Dashboard and authorize before UseXaf is used

        public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next) => next;

        public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> Dashboard = builder 
            => builder.UseHangfireDashboard(options:new DashboardOptions {Authorization = new[] {new DashboardAuthorization()}
        });
    }

    public class DashboardAuthorization : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter {
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
            => context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public class HangfireStartup : IHostingStartup{
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) 
            => builder.ConfigureServices(services => services
                .AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, UseHangfire>()
            );
    }
```

in the stripped out snippet you can see how I used the asp.net core [IHostingStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0) inside my library to register an [IStartupFilter](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-istartupfilter-in-asp-net-core/) which in his turn patch at runtime the `UseXaf` middleware (with the `OHarmony` library) to call the `UseHangfireDashboard` middleware at the exact point I needed.

Harder to describe in English that to type in C# :)

Caveats: depending on what actually want to patch you should be aware that compiler might inline it or not for different frameworks. Read more on their wiki [Inlining](https://harmony.pardeike.net/articles/patching-edgecases.html#inlining)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom Middleware class. This can either be by implementing the `IMiddleware` interface or just creating a class with a public method named `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync`. To add the middleware to your pipeline you can create a static method like so:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
}
```

then in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseCustomMiddleware();
```

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information on middleware.

Comment: Inject asp.net core middleware from a `library` to a specific location

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris put `app.UseCustomMiddleware()`  in your specific location. `app.UseCustomMiddleware()` can originate from a library. This answer is correct.

Comment: how you can insist on it? do you really think I ask how to type in certain location? I explicitly ask from inside a library.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can achieve this by creating an `IApplicationBuilder` and a `IStartupFilter` which than adds the middleware before or after a specific one. You need to add the filter in ConfigureServices with `services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, CustomStartupFilter>();`. A different approach can also be found [here](https://andrewlock.net/inserting-middleware-between-userouting-and-useendpoints-as-a-library-author-part-2/)

```
internal class CustomApplicationBuilder : IApplicationBuilder
{
    public CustomApplicationBuilder(IApplicationBuilder inner)
    {
        InnerBuilder = inner;
    }

    private IApplicationBuilder InnerBuilder { get; }

    public IServiceProvider ApplicationServices
    {
        get => InnerBuilder.ApplicationServices;
        set => InnerBuilder.ApplicationServices = value;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties => InnerBuilder.Properties;
    public IFeatureCollection ServerFeatures => InnerBuilder.ServerFeatures;
    public RequestDelegate Build() => InnerBuilder.Build();
    public IApplicationBuilder New() => InnerBuilder.New();

    public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
    {
        IApplicationBuilder builder = InnerBuilder.Use(middleware);
        if (Properties.ContainsKey("__AuthorizationMiddlewareSet") && !InnerBuilder.IsCustomMiddlewareSet())
        {
            //Add CustomMiddleware after AuthorizationMiddleware 
            return builder.UseCustomMiddleware();
        }

        return builder;
    }
}

internal class CustomStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            var wrappedBuilder = new CustomApplicationBuilder(builder);
            next(wrappedBuilder);
        };
    }
}

public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await next(context);
    }
}

public static class CustomMiddlewareExtensions
{
    internal const string CustomMiddlewareSetKey = "__CustomMiddlewareSet";

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Properties[CustomMiddlewareSetKey] = true;
        return app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
    }

    public static bool IsCustomMiddlewareSet(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        return app.Properties.ContainsKey(CustomMiddlewareSetKey);
    }
}
```